# Loop through list while also using if statement using Python not working

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am relatively new at Python and I am trying to scrape some baseball data using **beautifulSoup**, which requires me to know the player ID, the position they play, and I would like to know which side they bat from to determine which batting splits I need to grab. This is a very small section of my total program code using some testing data as I test small sections at a time.

I will need to loop over hundreds of players. However, it does not appear to be looping past the `[1] index` in my lists.  I have no idea why this isn't working, because I generally know how to use for loops.

Additionally, `while i = 1`, it is giving me a position of **F** which would be the **[1] character**, but I want the **[1] item** in the list (which would be `P`).

**The code is as follows:**

```
battingSide = ['R','L','S','R','S','R','R','L']
position =    ['OF','P','1B','2B','SS','3B','P','P','P','P','P','P','P']
playerID =    [123,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]


i = 0
while i < len(battingSide):
    position = position[i]
    activePlayerID = playerID[i]
    if battingSide[i] == 'R':
        print(i)
        splits = [0.3,0.4,0.5]
        print(splits)
        print(position)
        print(activePlayerID)
            i +=1
    elif battingSide[i] == 'L':
        splits = [0.1,0.2]
        print(splits)
        print(position)
        print(activePlayerID)
        print(playerID)
        i+=1
    else:
     #   print(i)
        splits = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
        print(splits)
        print(position)
        print(activePlayerID)
        print(playerID)
        i+=1   --(I'm not sure if I need this but I added it to try and fix the issue - however it didn't work)
```

**The error is as follows:**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/Schreier Family/Desktop/Python Programs/playerID - position - bats.py", line 8, in  position = position[i] IndexError: string index out of range

**The output I got before the error is as follows:**

```
0
[0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
F
123
[0.1, 0.2]
F
4
[123, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I continue to learn Python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn´t use the same name for the variable position and the array position:

```
position = position[i]
```

That line is not correct, because in the first iteration you loose the array, you must change it to samething like this:

```
actual_position = position[i]
```

and then you needo to change all the appearances of

```
print(position)
```

to

```
print(actual_position)
```

So you will have after some other changes to optimize:

```
battingSide = ['R','L','S','R','S','R','R','L']
position = ['OF','P','1B','2B','SS','3B','P','P','P','P','P','P','P']
playerID =    [123,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]

i = 0
while i < len(battingSide):
    actua_position = position[i]
    activePlayerID = playerID[i]
    print(i)
    if battingSide[i] == 'R':
        splits = [0.3,0.4,0.5]
    elif battingSide[i] == 'L':
        splits = [0.1,0.2]
    else:
        splits = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
    print(splits)
    print(actual_position)
    print(activePlayerID)
    print(playerID)
    i+=1
```

Comment: I like this as it simplifies things - however, I won't need all the prints at the end - that was more of a test feature to make sure if it was working or not.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't believe I missed that as I did change the playerID to activePlayerID for that reason.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you accidentally replace your list `position` by a variable `position` that contains the first element. Here is the modified version:

```
i = 0
while i < len(battingSide):
    pos = position[i]
    activePlayerID = playerID[i]
    if battingSide[i] == 'R':
        print(i)
        splits = [0.3,0.4,0.5]
        print(splits)
        print(pos)
        print(activePlayerID)
        i +=1
    elif battingSide[i] == 'L':
        splits = [0.1,0.2]
        print(splits)
        print(pos)
        print(activePlayerID)
        print(playerID)
        i+=1
    else:
     #   print(i)
        splits = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
        print(splits)
        print(pos)
        print(activePlayerID)
        print(playerID)
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
battingSide =['R','L','S','R','S','R','R','L']
position =['OF','P','1B','2B','SS','3B','P','P','P','P','P','P','P']
playerID =[123,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]
i=0
position1=[]*len(position)
while i < len(battingSide):
    position1 = position[i]
    activePlayerID = playerID[i]
    if battingSide[i] == 'R':
        print(i)
        splits = [0.3,0.4,0.5]
        print(splits)
        print(position1)
        print(activePlayerID)
        i +=1
    elif battingSide[i] == 'L':
        splits = [0.1,0.2]
        print(splits)
        print(position)
        print(activePlayerID)
        print(playerID)
        i+=1
    else:
     #   print(i)
        splits = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]
        print(splits)
        print(position1)
        print(activePlayerID)
        print(playerID)
        i+=1
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation around what you changed?

Comment: Position was re-initializing so I changed the name and just initialized a list of Len(position)

Comment: Edit your answer to add your explanation please.